# Constructing a continuous path between two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, path-connected, matrix-analysis

Let $A_1, A_2 \in GL_n(\mathbb R)$ be two fixed matrices with eigenvalues lying on the open left half plane of $\mathbb C$, i.e., with negative real parts and $A_1 \neq A_2$. We may assume $A_1, A_2$ are diagonalizable if necessary. Let $(A_1)_\alpha$ and $(A_2)_\beta$ be the corresponding matrix that scales the eigenvalues by $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ and $\beta \in \mathbb R$ respectively. That is if $(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n)$ are eigenvalues of $A_1$, then $(\alpha \lambda_1, \dots, \alpha \lambda_n)$ are eigenvalues of $(A_1)_{\alpha}$.

I am wondering whether it is possible to construct a continuous path $\gamma: [0,1] \to GL_n(\mathbb R)$ with eigenvalues all lying on the left half plane along the path: by choosing a sequence of nonzero real numbers, $(\alpha_n)$ and $(\beta_n)$, $\gamma$ is piecewise linear. For example, suppose there exist some finite sequences $(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_k)$ and $(\beta_1, \dots, \beta_l)$, then the path would be
\begin{align*}
A_1 \xrightarrow{} (A_1)_{\alpha_1} \xrightarrow{} \dots \xrightarrow{} (A_1)_{\alpha_k} \xrightarrow{}  (A_2)_{\beta_1} \xrightarrow{} \dots \xrightarrow{} (A_2)_{\beta_l} \xrightarrow{} A_2.
\end{align*}
In between, each arrow stands for a convex path. **Assume we can construct a continuous path between $A$ and $(A)_{\alpha}$**.

If we take a convex combination of $A_1, A_2$, i.e., $A(t) = (1-t)A_1 + tA_2$. Then $\det(A(t))$ is a nonconstant polynomial in $t$ and has at most $n$ zeros. Intuitively I am thinking of taking the path until we meet a singular point of $t$ (by continuity, all eigenvalues should stay in the left half plane) and change path to some $(A_1)_{\alpha}$ and doing this repeatedly. Not sure whether this will work.

p.s. The reason for my consideration was because I need to guarantee certain matrix structure along the path. I have worked out scaling eigenvalues can be done within the structure of interest.

Comment: I don't get your $A_\alpha$. How is it defined exactly? Is is simply $\alpha A$?

Comment: @user2520938: $(A)_{\alpha}$ has eigenvalues which are a factor of eigenvalues of $A$. $(A)_{\alpha} \neq \alpha A$ in general.

Comment: But that is not uniquely defined.... You need to be more specific

Comment: Yes. As I commented at the end, $A_1, A_2$ has some special structure and I would like to construct a path within this structure. I figured out we can scale eigenvalues within the structure.

Comment: @user9527 That doesn't answer the question at all. $A_a$ is not well defined. Is that not a problem? What exactly is the continuous path $\gamma$?

Comment: @JackM: Sorry it is not clear enough. I took out some background. The question is like this: suppose we have some specified structure $\star$ on $M_n(\mathbb R)$ and let $A_1, A_2$ respect this structure. Now I want prove $A_1$ and $A_2$ are connected within this structure $\star$. I have proved we can construct $(A_1)_{\alpha}$ with respect to the structure and also $A_1, (A_1)_{\alpha}$ can be connected by a path. My question is whether we can use these information to connect $A_1, A_2$.

Comment: @JackM: It possible these information is not enough. Then I have to continue working on the structure $\star$ to find more information.

Comment: So you have a set of matrices $M$. You know that if $A\in M$, then for any $a\in\mathbb R$ there exists a matrix $A_a\in M$ whose eigenvalues are $a$ times those of $A$, and which can be connected to $A$ via a continuous path in $M$. You want to know if this is enough to prove that $A_1$ and $A_2$ (which are in $M$) can be path-connected?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly my situation.